# Sony Vaio S (SVS151C1GL) Auto Dimming Issue

Tags: windows-8, drivers, display, sony-vaio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable the light sensor on a Vaio laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/127835/how-to-disable-the-light-sensor-on-avaio-laptop)

I recently purchased a Sony Vaio S 15-inch laptop running Windows 8.  For some reason, I cannot manually adjust the screen brightness, it always goes down to a minimal setting because of the auto brightness detection.  If I change the screen brightness manually, it will stay that way for 3-5 seconds and then go back down to the very dark setting.

I saw a post ([Sony VAIO dim screen on Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/490893/sony-vaio-dim-screen-on-windows-8)) and this is exactly what is happening, but those drivers (specifically the Intel Graphics Media Accelerator HD Driver Update) will not run on my system.

Has anyone been able to find the right drivers or solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Search for `Power options`. Open the control panel that comes up, click on "Change plan settings" for whatever power plan is active, then select (At the bottom of the new screen) "Change advanced power settings". In the new window, click the UAC icon to enable changes. Scroll down to "Display", expand to show "Enable adaptive brightness". Disable it for both states. Press apply and see if Windows respects your manual configuration now.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I open up the "Change advanced power settings" and go to the display options, there is no option to enable/disable adaptive brightness.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that worked for me, if anyone else is having this problem try the solution from this post: [How to disable the light sensor on a Vaio laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/127835/how-to-disable-the-light-sensor-on-avaio-laptop)